# Dynamically add object to array in R

Tags: r

Taking a quick break from iOS dev and trying to implement a pretty simple task using R but I cannot figure out how to resolve this error, can someone please help?

```
setClass(
    "Player",
    representation(name="character", position="character", adp="numeric", points="numeric"),
    prototype(name=NA_character_, position=NA_character_, adp=NA_real_, points=NA_real_)
)



setwd("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/fantasy")
playersADP = read.csv("adp_test.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
print(nrow(playersADP))

players <- 1:nrow(playersADP)

for(i in 1:nrow(playersADP)) {
    player <- new("Player",
        name = playersADP[i,3],
        position = playersADP[i,4],
        adp = playersADP[i,1]
    )
    players[i] = player
}
print(players)
```

When I run the above script this is the error I get "Error in players[i] = player : incompatible types (from S4 to integer) in subassignment type fix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the array is not working as you expect.

This line creates an array of 1 to `nrow(playersADP)`:

```
players <- 1:nrow(playersADP)   # Gives you [1, 2, 3, ...]
```

This creates an array of integers. These are incompatible with the S4 type, so when you try to set a value to an S4, you get a type problem:

```
players[i] = player   # Crashes because players is an array of integers, but player is not an integer
```

What you want is this:

```
players <- c()    # Create an empty array
```

Then to add to it:

```
players <- c(players, player)
```